# Efficiently construct numpy matrix from offset ranges of 1D array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

Let's say I have a 1D array of data. I want to (efficiently) produce an matrix, such that
each row of the matrix is a contiguous range of values in the data array, and each row of
the matrix is offset (in the original data array) by 1, with respect to the previous row.

This example will probably make that a little easier to understand:

```
# fake data, for demonstration
data = np.arange(100) 

# some parameters
offset = 4
span = 10
n = 20

# one way to do this, I'm guessing the for loop is not the most efficient
np.stack([data[i+offset:i+offset+span] for i in range(n)])
```

Which produces:

```
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
       [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
       [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]])
```

I've obviously already figured out how to do this, but I think that there must be a more efficient numpythonic way to do it that avoids the for-loop/stack. I'm going to need to do this a lot (in another loop) and would like to maximize the performance.

TIA

Comment: Slice `data[offset:offset+n+span-1]` and use the linked Q&A.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected someone must have asked something similar before, but wasn't able to come up with a search query that gave me any relevant hits.